# how to sort alphanumeric string and change sequence?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

If its duplicate question please suggest me that link,

my code is

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      String name ="h498y948759hrh98A722hjDF94yugerTEr892ur48y";
      char[] arr= name.toCharArray();
      Arrays.sort(arr);
      System.out.println(arr);
}
```

and result is

```
 222444457788888999999ADEFTeghhhhjrrrruuyyy
```

now i want to chnage the sequence of this sorting like
ADEFT222444457788888999999eghhhhjrrrruuyyy or
eghhhhjrrrruuyyy222444457788888999999ADEFT

so question is how can i change this sequence?
and if this is wrong way of sorting then please tell me right one.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own `Comparator` class/object and pass it to `Arrays.sort()`.  Unfortunately, you also need to convert the elements to `Character`.

However, perhaps the most general way is to see each character as a `String` and use a `Collator`, as in the following example:

```
    //  Rules separated in 3 parts only for convenience
    String rules1= "< A < B < C < D < E < F < G < H < I < J < K < L < M < N < O < P < Q < R < S < T < U < V < W < X < Y < Z" ;
    String rules2= "< a < b < c < d < e < f < g < h < i < j < k < l < m < n < o < p < q < r < s < t < u < v < w < x < y < z" ;
    String rules3= "< 0 < 1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5 < 6 < 7 < 8 < 9" ;
    RuleBasedCollator collator= new RuleBasedCollator(rules1+rules2+rules3) ;

    String input= "h498y948759hrh98A722hjDF94yugerTEr892ur48y" ;

    //  Bulk of the job done here
    String[] arr= input.split("") ;
    Arrays.sort(arr,1,arr.length,collator);

    //  Join back in a single string for presentation
    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder() ;
    for(String e: arr )
        sb.append( e );
    System.out.println(sb);
```

Output is

```
    ADEFTeghhhhjrrrruuyyy222444457788888999999
```

Changing only collation rules to

```
    String rules1= "< 0 < 1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5 < 6 < 7 < 8 < 9" ;
    String rules2= "< A,a < B,b < C,c < D,d < E,e < F,f < G,g < H,h < I,i < J,j < K,k < L,l < M,m < N,n < O,o < P,p < Q,q < R,r < S,s < T,t < U,u < V,v < W,w < X,x < Y,y < Z,z" ;
    RuleBasedCollator collator= new RuleBasedCollator(rules1+rules2) ;
```

Output is

```
    222444457788888999999ADEeFghhhhjrrrrTuuyyy
```

The main advantage of `Collator`s is that they allow to sort multi-character Strings according to their internal rules.  In fact, this is their main use case.

Pretty powerful, eh?  (Yes, I'm Canadian in case you didn't guess :-) )

Comment: Yes, though you'd have to convert the `char[]` to a `Character[]` first, since `Arrays.sort(char[])` does not have a version that uses a `Comparator` (since `Comparator` cannot work with primitive types).

Comment: +1 for using a collation-based approach; it's been a long time since I've seen any use of a collator. Also, I must be missing something; I don't see anything in your answer (except the last sentence) that might hint at your being Canadian, unless "pretty powerful, eh" is supposed to be a Canadian idiom or something. :-P (I'm a New Zealander, by the way.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young  According to popular culture we tend to end each sentence in "eh?".  But we take it with humor, eh?

Comment: @VeronicaCornejo Lol. I'm sure Kiwis and Brits end sentences with "eh" pretty frequently too, so it wouldn't be unusual for me to hear, eh? :-P

Comment: @VeronicaCornejo can the collator be used to sort alpha numerically?This might not be part of what OP was expecting to be answered but I believe this is a limitation of using a collator based approach?

Answer (score 3):

I've written some sample to demonstrate the `Comparator` concept. It requires [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.collect.ComparisonChain;
import com.google.common.primitives.Chars;

public class Test {
    private enum Comparators implements Comparator<Character> {
        UPPER_DIGIT_LOWER {
            @Override
            int compare(char lhs, char rhs) {
                return ComparisonChain.start()
                        .compareTrueFirst(Character.isUpperCase(lhs), Character.isUpperCase(rhs))
                        .compareTrueFirst(Character.isDigit(lhs), Character.isDigit(rhs))
                        .compareTrueFirst(Character.isLowerCase(lhs), Character.isLowerCase(rhs))
                        .compare(lhs, rhs)
                        .result();
            }
        },
        LOWER_DIGIT_UPPER {
            @Override
            int compare(char lhs, char rhs) {
                return ComparisonChain.start()
                        .compareTrueFirst(Character.isLowerCase(lhs), Character.isLowerCase(rhs))
                        .compareTrueFirst(Character.isDigit(lhs), Character.isDigit(rhs))
                        .compareTrueFirst(Character.isUpperCase(lhs), Character.isUpperCase(rhs))
                        .compare(lhs, rhs)
                        .result();
            }
        };

        @Override
        public int compare(Character lhs, Character rhs) {
            return compare(lhs.charValue(), rhs.charValue());
        }

        abstract int compare(char lhs, char rhs);
    }

    private static String sortChars(String str, Comparator<Character> cmp) {
        List<Character> chars = Chars.asList(str.toCharArray());
        Collections.sort(chars, cmp);
        return new String(Chars.toArray(chars));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "h498y948759hrh98A722hjDF94yugerTEr892ur48y";
        System.out.println(sortChars(name, Comparators.UPPER_DIGIT_LOWER));
        System.out.println(sortChars(name, Comparators.LOWER_DIGIT_UPPER));
    }
}
```